# how to add a selector to a view programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

i have a linearlayout and as shown below in code1 i add to it a background to change its appearance/background when selected.

in code2 below, i inflate a view and i want to add the same selector/background 'android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator"'
to the view inflated in code2

how can i do that programmatically?

**code1**:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/versicherungs_verDetailsListFooter_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/vers_height"
            android:layout_below="@id/horizontalDivider0"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">
```

**code2**:

```
final LinearLayout linLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.versicherungs_verDetailsListFooter_container);

    LayoutInflater inflator = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.versicherungs_docs_footer, null);

    RelativeLayout relLay = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.versicherungs_footer_mainContainer);
    final TextView texVieShowMore = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showMore);
    final TextView texVieShowLess = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showLess);
    final TextView texVieShowMoreArrow = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showMoreArrow);
    final TextView texVieShowLessArrow = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showLessArrow);

    //how to add the selector "?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator" to the RelativeLayout "relLay"
```

Comment: i think `Theme#resolveAttribute` will do the trick of getting the `resourceId`

Comment: @pskink would u please provide an example

Comment: i dont have any

Comment: @pskink do u mean i should use theme.reolveAttribute?

Comment: yes, i mean so...

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve attribute from theme:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
if (getTheme() != null) {
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.listChoiceBackgroundIndicator, typedValue, true);
}
int drawableResourceId = typedValue.resourceId; // it can by equal 0
```

and then set view's background resource:

```
relLay.setBackgroundResource(drawableResourceId);
```

Comment: i tried your suggested answer..but unfortunately when i click on the view it doesnt change as if no attribute assigned to as a selector/background

Comment: Is flag `clickable` set to true for `relLay` layout in xml ? if not use `relLay.setClickable(true)`. PS. default `listChoiceBackgroundIndicator` supports only disabled/pressed/focused state (it doesn't support selected state) https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml